# Detect if using retina display from python

Tags: python, osx

I've got some BGL drawing code which draws some outlines over nodes in screen-space coordinates. It accounts for the DPI settings in the User Preferences and scales up the size and position of drawn objects accordingly.

The problem is, if a user is using a Retina display, the DPI value in the preferences doesn't actually change, even though it virtually doubles, thus the screen coordinates are all wrong:

[image: screenshot]

The red outlines are supposed to sit exactly on top of the nodes. This works fine on a non-retina display.

**So how can I check whether blender is running on a Retina display from python?**

The code is all here: http://hastebin.com/gipifamoco.py - at line `607` is where I take into account the DPI and 
"Virtual Pixel Mode" option in the user prefs (which can be set to 'Double' to simulate using a Retina display, but stays at 'Native' when using an actual Retina display)

So theoretically I'd like to be able to change:

`retinafac = (2 if bpy.context.user_preferences.system.virtual_pixel_mode == 'DOUBLE' else 1)`

to:

`retinafac = (2 if (bpy.context.user_preferences.system.virtual_pixel_mode == 'DOUBLE' or <using retina display>) else 1)`

where `<using retina display>` is the check.

Comment: Do you use the command line option --no-native-pixels  "Do not use native pixel size, for high resolution displays (MacBook 'Retina')" Found here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Command_Line

Comment: I know that option exists, but I'm not sure how it would help me. I simply want to check if the user is using a retina display.

Comment: Added access to pixelsize: eg. `bpy.context.user_preferences.system.pixel_size` https://developer.blender.org/rB8350f7a587c7a6824f48f3edb936b49ce3462336

Comment: @ideasman42: you should make that an answer (wasn't possible so far, but will be in future). Kudos for exposing it to Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can can now access the pixel size with `bpy.context.user_preferences.system.pixel_size` ([commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB8350f7a587c7a6824f48f3edb936b49ce3462336))

This works for retina scale or `bpy.context.user_preferences.system.virtual_pixel_mode`